# rounding off to 3 decimal values for the value that uses i18n (regional setting) in vue.js - vue-i18n

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-i18n

I have a method to return the result value,

```
---------
        const values = 123.10000;
        const result = i18n.n(values, 'number');
        return result;
--------
```

In the above ,I need to round off the result to 3 decimal point , I tired tofixed , rounD off method but the zeros are not be included in it .

expected output
result is `123.100.`

but i am getting `123.1`   ,
how should i add the decimal round off method to 3 decimal digits with the values having zeros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use this.

The toFixed() method formats a number using fixed-point notation. [ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

```
const values = 123.1;
const result = values.toFixed(3);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: i need to have the  i18n.n(values, 'number'); method